# Как вызвать magnific popup без клика?

Tags: javascript, api, popup, magnific

Как можно вызвать Magnific Popup без клика на кнопку? Я нашел паблик методы в документации, но не могу разобраться как реализовать.

Пример: http://playcode.io/146240?tabs=console&script.js&output

Как можно через консоль например вызвать окно, которое имеется?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод

```
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup('open');
```

Подробнее и другие методы в [документации](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api)